# How do cheat codes work on Rising Kingdoms?

Tags: cheats, rising-kingdoms

According to several websites, on the RTS Rising Kingdoms there are only 7 cheats. According to one of the websites ([gamefaqs.com](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/926770-rising-kingdoms/cheats)):

> To enter these cheats hit enter while playing to bring up the chat window and type the codes in, then hit enter again when finished.

However, this does not work, as any and all cheats I tried just come up as regular chat. I tried this both in campaign and custom modes. How do cheats /actually/ work in Rising Kingdoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The method was completly right.** The sole reason it was not working is that it appears cheat codes were disabled in Patch 1.40, as they able to be used on other patches.